# Drupal Translations

Tags: i18n-l10n, importing-exporting

I'm downloading .po files from http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads which is great for Drupal Core translations, but I'm wondering if it's possible to download a .po file which could update custom text/menu items/etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module you can both export and import custom translations for your site which sit outside of any other module translation.  The module groups translations by source including the Built-in interface, Blocks, CCK, Content types, Menus and Taxonomy depending on which submodules you enable.